# Sum of all contiguous subarrays optimisation

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, optimization

I am solving a problem where I have an array and for two given indices `min` and `max`, I need to find sum of all contiguous sub-arrays between them.

All I could think is of this *O*(*n*<sup>2</sup>) code

```
for (int i = min; i <= max; ++i)
{
    long long sum = 0;
    for (int j = i; j <= max; ++j)
    {
        sum += a[j];
        printf("%lld\n", sum);
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help me with optimising this code?

Comment: Are you looking for [`std::partial_sum`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sum)?

Comment: Is this c or c++, it's no the same.

Comment: @OllieFord Can you give a sample case which it misses. I couldn't find any such case.

Comment: "Sum of all subarrays" is a total of **one** number. If you need one number per subarray, that would be "sums of all subarrays". Decide what you want.

Comment: (this could be because it's monday morning, first day of the year for me..) but surely what you are doing is the equivalent of, sum all the values between min and max, and the simply iterate through subtracting the value at the current index (from the last total) to the give you the sum of the following values?

Comment: @n.m. I think "sum of each" is the clearest language - OP states code works, so that is clearly intention. Vinay - apologies, I was mistaken, it doesn't miss the case I was thinking.

Answer (score 5):

Using dynamic programming you can achieve `O(n)` answer. The idea basically is to calculate prefix sums accumulated for all elements.

Let `A(i)` be the summation of elements from `0` to `i`. This can be calculated easily in `O(n)` by:

```cpp
// let your array by Src[Max]
int A[MAX];
A[0] = Src[0];

for(int i = 1; i < MAX; i++) {
    A[i] += A[i - 1] + (i + 1) * Src[i];
}
```

Then for any elements `i` and `j`, you can calculate `sum(i,j) = A[j] - A[i]`  (adjust for boundaries depending on input requirements).

Comment: Why `(i+1)` in the `(i+1)*Src[i]` part?...

Answer (score 2):

There is no faster solution.

Since your output size is O(n<sup>2</sup>), not algorithm can be faster.

Comment: What if I need not print for every sum. But need to check for some condition?

Comment: das blinken light ist völlig right! And apart from the fact that the results are wrong, if you want to check O(n^2) results, you won't be faster than O(n^2). Maybe you can optimize the check to make it at fast as possible, but there is no way to improve it to something like O(nlogn),

Comment: Could improve by some careful memoisation of partial sums.

Comment: That's what dasblinkenlight wrote: An optimized correct implementation is O(n^2).

Answer (score 2):

When `max-min+1` is `n`, there would be `n(n-1)/2` sums that you need to print. That's O(n<sup>2</sup>) values. The fastest possible algorithm to produce O(n<sup>2</sup>) values would have time complexity of O(n<sup>2</sup>), so your solution is already optimal.

Answer (score 0):

For **insanely** large block of computation or things like real time data analysis, since the content of arrays do not change, you may do the calculation in parallel threads.

For general cases, just loop them and let the compiler unroll and use vectorized instructions.